# Best way to write a constructor that could have invalid parameters

Tags: c++, code-readability

I have a question about writing readable and efficient code in C++.

I’m creating a class for tcp connections with a constructor that takes as input the IP of the server and the port. I would like to avoid the creation of the object if for example the IP is wrong.

My question is:

> Is it better to throw an exception in case of a failure or create a
>   wrapper class with a Boolean to check if the internal object was
>   created correctly and avoid calling any functions in case of failure?

Comment: [The "standard" answer to your question](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#ctors-can-throw). Or you can use factory pattern.

Comment: a function that returns a `std::optional<connection>` if you can use c++17

Comment: You can also follow https://wg21.link/p0323 for a possible future option.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing in a constructor upon invalid input is fine and even recommend by the [core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c42-if-a-constructor-cannot-construct-a-valid-object-throw-an-exception).

Named constructors (i.e. static member functions) are an equally valid approach, they could e.g. return a `std::optional<YourType>` (C++17 is required, then). This makes it obvious that the instantiation could fail and circumvents the drawbacks of exceptions. Here's a small example.

```
#include <optional>

class Example {
    public:
       static std::optional<Example> validateAndCreate(...);

    private:
       /* Private ctor makes usage of the above function mandatory. */
       Example(...);
};
```

And an implementation of the creation method could be

```
std::optional<Example> validateAndCreate(...)
{
    /* Use e.g. some utility function for validation: */
    if (isInputValid(/* Pass parameter. */))
        return Example(/* Pass parameter. */);
    else
        return std::nullopt;
}
```

where client code then constructors objects like this:

```
if (const auto instance = Example::validateAndCreate())
    /* Do stuff with the instance. */
    ;
else
    std::cerr << "What now?\n";
```

I guess this approach is more self-documenting (the fact that a ctor might throw should be documented somewhere), but also more verbose.

Comment: interesting method indeed. Just one question, does that mean that the variable is always allocated dynamically??

Comment: No, `std::optional` owns its data and does not allocate. It's like the ordinary return value plus a `bool`ean flag.